# Importing .sql file into IBM DB2 Express-C

Tags: sql, db2

Hello I' new to IBM DB2 Express-C

I have a exported a database to .sql file (Original database stored in SQLite3 - used SQLite SQLite Manager for exporting the the database to a .sql file)

Can anyone please tell a way to import a this .sql file into DB2. Thank you

Comment: What is the content of that file? DDL sentences? DML? DCL?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a set of sentences in a file in DB2, you issue in the command line (db2clp):

```
db2 -tvf <filename>
```

For exmpale, for your file

```
db2 -tvf myfile.sql
```

However, the content of that file could not be compliant with DB2, and you have to modify it, in order to run correctly in DB2.

Basic Create tables, and DML (insert, delete, update) are SQL 92 standard accross many database. But if you have create bufferpool, tablespaces, and other kind of objects, you have tomodify the file a lot.

Comment: I'm importing create table statements as well.

Comment: Note that the -v option stands for *verbose* so you might want to remove it